# How to read selective data from SQLite?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I would like to read from SQLite DB the data that stored in the id 10 to 20.
What do I need to add / change in the following code?

```
    mNumOneTest = new Vector<Test>();
    DiagnoseTestOpenHelper helper = new DiagnoseTestOpenHelper(
            TestOneTimeTable.this);
    mDb = helper.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM TEST;", null);
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        do {
            Test test = new Test();
            test.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
            test.setNumber_one(cursor.getInt(1));
            test.setNumber_two(cursor.getInt(2));
            mNumOneTest.add(test);

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
```

Comment: Really, you couldn't be bothered to read *a little bit* about SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your SQL to `SELECT * FROM TEST WHERE id >= 10 AND id <= 20`

Answer (score 1):

```
"SELECT * FROM TEST WHERE id >= 10 AND id <= 20"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM TEST WHERE id BETWEEN 10 AND 20
```

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to read from SQLite DB the data that stored in the id 10
>   to 20. What do I need to add / change in the follow ing code?

You need to learn [`SQL basics`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp) because this is very "primitive" question and when you want to work with any database, clauses as `WHERE`, `LIKE` etc. you should know.

You can do it with `between` and clause, `in` clause or simply with `<>=` operands

```
where id between 10 and 20
where id >= 10 and id <=20
```